# How to remove in correct way qt4 development libraries?

Tags: qt, removing

Since I am using **Qt5** stuff which installed in **/opt** directory and about to install **Ubuntu SDK** seems like **Qt4** packages will be redundant in my system. Moreover I am not in need exactly **Qt4** libs. So how can I do that *(subject)*? Thanks!

Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Did you install them using apt-get? If so you should just be able to use `apt-get purge`

Comment: Thanks. Yep, by apt-get. But purge what? I have many installed qt4-related packages:  
http://pastebin.com/BJTX0yAN  
I'm not sure for some libqt4-* package - it may will be needed by some other package...

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt purge qt4*
```

This will uninstall qt4 and it's deps