# "Could not start D-Bus. Could you call qdbus?" error. Any ides how to fix it?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde, dbus, qdbus

I installed CodeBlocks from terminal with command `sudo apt-get install codeblocks` on Kubuntu 14.04 and then file manager started lag. I restarted computer and had error "Could not start d-bus. Can you call qdbus?".

I have tried all suggestions in the google. I saw it was a bug. Somebody had solved the problem for example by removing quotes in `qdbus="QT_SELECT=qt4 qdbus"`. I have tried it.I also tried reinstall kde, qt, xorg. But for me nothing had helped.

Any ides what I could try to fix this situation? Could it be this error for installing CodeBlocks?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dbus`

Comment: Tried, not working.

Comment: Did you reboot it?

Comment: What is the output of `ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin`?

Comment: Yes, I rebooted it. Command shows files: lrelease, lupdate, moc, qdbus, qdbuscpp2xml, qdbusxml2cpp, qmake, qt3to4, qtconfig, rcc, uic, uic3.

Comment: what is the output of `qtchooser -print-env`?

Comment: Try to reinstall `sudo apt-get install --reinstall qt4-default`

Comment: Output `QT_SELECT="default" QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin" QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"`

Comment: Also there is another error `Could not conncent to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11"`

Comment: Tried your last command, but nothing. Only `QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin"` changed to `QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin"`

Comment: Did you revert the changes to `qdbus="QT_SELECT=qt4 qdbus"` in the `/usr/bin/startkde`?

Comment: Yes. Then I get error `Could not start kdeinit4. Check your installation.`

Comment: Did you try https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-workspace/+bug/1304805 #23? but before doing that try `qdbus=QT_SELECT=qt4 qdbus` if it launches `dbus`

Comment: No, it shows previous error. If change in `startkde` `qt4` to `qt5` then `dbus` error gone and shows another error `Could not start kdeinit4. Check your installation.`.

Comment: Try to reinstall `qt5-dbus`

Comment: Reinstalling didn't help. Still the same errors as `could not start D-Bus` or `could not start kdeinit4`

Answer (score 0):

With a command `qtchooser -l` and the command `sudo apt purge qt4*` (this link [How to remove in correct way qt4 development libraries?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602614/how-to-remove-in-correct-way-qt4-development-libraries)) I deleted all qt libraries and installed `qt4-default` and it helped me. Earlier I tried to reinstall qt, but I think it was not a full uninstall and it cause not working for me.